# Sed: output value of capturing group into a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm using sed to capture text, run external commands and output value of capturing group to screen and into a file.

This is an example of command I need:

```
echo testme | sed -r 's/([a-z]{4}).*/'"$(echo "\1" | tee out.txt)"'/g'
```

That is, I need to output value (***test***) of capturing group (***\1***)  to a file.

But while on the screen I can see right text:

```
test
```

in a file I see the following:

```
\1
```

Seems that notation of capturing group doesn't expand its value when output to file instead of screen.

Please, tell me what do I do wrong and how to output value of capturing group into a file.

Please, if possible - no solutions with grep/awk. I need to do that using sed (or maybe ssed).

Thanks!

Comment: How about the others that doesn't match? How would they appear in stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/([a-z]{4}).*/!b;s//\1/;w out.txt' file
```

or:

```
sed -rn 's/([a-z]{4}).*/\1/p;T;s/.*/echo "&" | tee out.txt/e' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do it this way but I'm not sure if it's what you really want:

```
echo testme | tee >(sed -r 's/([a-z]{4}).*/\1/g' > out.txt)
```

It would send testme unmodified on the screen while the filtered version would be sent to out.txt.

If you want to send both filtered version to screen and file, you can just use tee at the last part:

```
echo testme | sed -r 's/([a-z]{4}).*/\1/g' | tee out.txt
```

Appending versions:

```
echo testme | tee >(sed -r 's/([a-z]{4}).*/\1/g' >> out.txt)

echo testme | sed -r 's/([a-z]{4}).*/\1/g' | tee -a out.txt
```